# Mail header to disable bounce emails

Tags: email

I am sending emails for newsletter subscription, where I get a lot of spam by bots.

Now I would like to send the opt-in email for the newsletter in a way that the mail server does not return any bounces to me.

I know I can set `Return-Path` to an unused mail account, but how to tell the mail server not to send any bounces? Any way I can set it to void?

I looked at [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321.html#section-3.3) but I did not find anything for my case. Return-Path is defined as:

```
Return-path-line  = "Return-Path:" FWS Reverse-path <CRLF>
```

`FWS` is defined in [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.2):

```
FWS             =   ([*WSP CRLF] 1*WSP) /  obs-FWS
                   ; Folding white space
```

Or is there any other header for this?

**Update**

`Return-Path` is set by the mail server you send the mail to. As a sender you can not (or should not) set it yourself. But you can set `From` and `Reply-To` to `void@example.com` because example.com is a [reserved domain](https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved).

Comment: I guess not :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the envelope from, in sendmail that is the `-f` parameter:

```
   -f sender
          Set  the  envelope sender address. This is the address where de‐
          livery problems are sent to. With Postfix versions  before  2.1,
          the  Errors-To:  message  header  overrides the error return ad‐
          dress.
```

I still would suggest to use a valid mail address and just discard the mail. Not sure if it would cause trouble for example with spam reputation if you use `@example.com` or `@example.invalid`

Comment: I used -f noreply@mydomain.com and created an account for the address. Also I added a filter to move every mail to trash and empty the trash every day. That should do the trick.

Comment: Ignoring bounces sounds like a recipe for getting yourself blocked eyerywhere over time.